# Rails: Manipulating a Join Table in a Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, join

I have two models connected by a join table:

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :author_attributes, :translator_attributes

  has_many :publication_contributors
  has_many :authors, :through => :publication_contributors, :source => :contributor,
    :conditions => {:publication_contributors => {:contributor_type => "Author"}}
  has_many :translators, :through => :publication_contributors, :source => :contributor,
    :conditions => {:publication_contributors => {:contributor_type => "Translator"}}

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors, :translators
end

class Contributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :publications, :through => :publication_contributors
  has_many :publication_contributors
end

class PublicationContributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contributor_type

  belongs_to :publication
  belongs_to :contributor
end
```

Note that the join table has a third attribute (beside publication_id and contributor_id), which is called contributor_type. This attribute might contain a role such as "Author", "Translator", "Editor", or something else. In my Publication model, I created a pair of associations for two of the more common contributor_types, "Author" and "Translator". These associations work well at retrieving the relevant data, such as with `@publication.authors`. It sputters when creating these associations through a nested form, however.

My form looks something like this:

```
<%= form_for @publication, :remote => true do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>:
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.fields_for :authors do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :name, "Author" %>:
    <%= builder.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :translators do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :name, "Translator" %>:
    <%= builder.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller:

```
def create
  publication = Publication.create(params[:publication])
end
```

The form renders as expected, but it sputters during the create action. I had hoped that Rails would know to magically assign the proper contributor_type based on the conditions in the Publication associations, such as:

```
has_many :authors, :through => :publication_contributors, :source => :contributor,
:conditions => {:publication_contributors => {:contributor_type => "Author"}}
```

Unfortunately, it does not. I get this error during creation:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'contributor_type' cannot be null
```

This makes me think that my only recourse is to manually assign the contributor_type in a `before_create` callback, but if that's the case, how do I determine which type to assign? The parameters have the proper type in their name, for instance:

```
publication[authors_attributes][0][name]
```

Is there some way to access that information in the model layer?

UPDATE:

My `new` action:

```
def new
  @publication = Publication.new
  publication_contributor = @publication.publication_contributors.build
  contributor = publication_contributor.contributor.build
end
```

It throws this error on the final line (the one setting `contributor`):

```
undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: can you try adding a hidden field on the form instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would help. The `contributor_type` attribute is in the join table, not in the Contributor model. Since I'm not actually declaring the join table within the form, I don't have access to its attributes, even with a hidden field. Perhaps if there is a way to create the join table within the form, however, this approach could work. I'll look into this. Let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: you're right. is it fine if you go through publication_contributor and then contributor?

Comment: I'll give that shot and see how it works out.

Comment: Not sure it's possible. In order to get it to work, I'd have to create an instance of Contributor off of PublicationContributor like so: `publication_contributor.contributor.new`. This throws a `undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass` error. I get the same results with `.build`. I wonder if ActiveRecord doesn't support nesting from child to parent. The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) don't mention this situation one way or the other.

Comment: it should be possible.  but since you're using accepts_nested_attributes_for, you need to build the objects.  I'll post an answer for this solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :publication_contributors_attributes

  has_many :publication_contributors
  has_many :authors, through: :publication_contributors, source: :contributor, conditions: { publication_contributors: { contributor_type: 'Author' } }
  has_many :translators, through: :publication_contributors, source: :contributor, conditions: { publication_contributors: { contributor_type: 'Translator' } }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :publication_contributors
end

class Contributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :publications, through: :publication_contributors
  has_many :publication_contributors
end

class PublicationContributor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contributor_type

  belongs_to :publication
  belongs_to :contributor

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contributor
end

<%= form_for @publication, :remote => true do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>:
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.fields_for :publication_contributors do |pc_form| %>
    <%= pc_form.hidden_field :contributor_type %>
    <%= pc_form.fields_for :contributor do |c_form| %>
      <%= c_form.label :name, "Author" %>:
      <%= c_form.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE: controller code

```
@publication.publication_contributors.build
@publication.publication_contributors.each do |pc|
  pc.build_contributor
end
```

Comment: Gave this shot, but I'm still getting the build error. It's curious that a similar situation works on this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

Comment: i've updated my answer with what should your controller should at least look like :)

Comment: Of course! Even though I'd only created one of them, publication_contributors was still an association. What's curious is that I can't set it with `publication_contributors = @publication.publication_contributors.build` and then access it directly with `publication_contributors.each`. Your code works perfectly, though. So thanks! It's just baffling me that I can't access publication_contributors directly.